# How to downgrade D-Link DAP 1360 revision B from 2.11 to 2.10?

Tags: dhcp-server

I have a  dap 1360 and made a upgrade to version 2.11. Now if I set up an access point with it I cant use the integrated DHCP server the device has. When I go to the page where Enable DHCP Server was, its missing. I noticed the option is there in HTML code but is inside a div with a hidden style. So I wonder why this option was hidden. I should be adviced that this updrade would hurt me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to just provide the router the firmware and load the firmware. If you have the firmware thats entirely seperate story.  I would avoid using old firmware there are TWO MAJOR exploits that have been released in the last 2 years in the wild that effect LITERALLY EVER ROUTER on the market.

Comment: I cant load the old firewall since decive prevent me to upload old firmware. Is that exploit about DHCP Server?

Comment: No...Has to do with upnp being visable outside of your local network. This bug has unlikely been fixed. I am more worried about the wps exploit that allows somebody to brute force your wps key to access your local network.

Comment: Wow, a downvote! Why this time?

Answer (score 0):

I got a down vote, but anyways this is my answer. I update an upgrade of the firmware revB 2.14 form this link: http://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/ftp.dlink.es/DAP/DAP-1360/Firmware/B1/2.14b05. Im not sure if I should trust this, but anyways I only turn on this router when there are visits at home. Anyway, DHCP Server worked for me.

Comment: please, could you share the firmware? the link is broken....